# Is there a way to simulate slow connections in Apache?

Tags: apache, simulation

My app is too fast at localhost and internet connections here at my city are not that good. So wanted to simulate a slow connection under Apache. Can it do this?

obs: I'm using WAMP to develop under Windows 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [NetLimiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/). It has a free lite version that lets you limit upload and download rates per specific application.

Comment: I couldn't find anything about that on their website - plus, it's a 30 day trial. NetLimiter (http://www.netlimiter.com) has a free "Lite" version which, according to their feature list, can limit upload and download rates per application.

Comment: Oops, forgot the link. Added to the comment.

Comment: NetLimiter works like a charm, thank you! - could you change your answer to it for me to accept? (: